# Create and animate a negative height div?

Tags: css

Building a special curve, I have a square element `div` that need to be fixed to it's bottom line while height will be changed(using animation) from the top:
[image]

I was trying to set **negative height**, and position the div on the y of the purple line, but that didn't work.

If I just add a normal `div` with a *y offset*, I can't animate it from top.

How to setup this `div` so I can easily animate its height to move as in the picture?

btw - this div must be `absolute` positioned.

```
    .element{
        width: 40px;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    <div class="element"></div>
    element.style.height = 60 + 'px'
```

Comment: A negative height doesn't exist, but you can definitely make the bottom stay fixed and animate the regular height. Do you have any code so far?

Comment: How can I do this? i didn't even know what term to search for. I have a basic code of a div which won't add much value to this question.

Comment: If you are using absolute positioning, then you could just set the `bottom` to, e.g. `0` (Fixed to the bottom of the closest `position: relative` parent element), and then animate the `height`

Comment: If you put even your basic code into your question it could help us - in particular if the div is positioned absolute, in relation to what other element is it positioned (ie which is its closest ancestor with a position?). You can then fix it with bottom:0 if that's the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` is what keeps it at the bottom and then you can just make height change with `@keyframes`.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  
  position: relative;
}

.animated {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 0px;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 animation: grow 4s infinite;

}

@keyframes grow {
   0%   { height: 200px; }
   50%  { height: 0px; }
   100% { height: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="animated"></div>
</div>
```

*******EDIT******
Edit for the comment under so you can set css variable with javascript and then use that variable to set your height of the element and use same variable to set your animation.

```js
/* sets height variable */
let myHeight = 100;
var r = document.querySelector(':root');
r.style.setProperty('--height', (myHeight + 'px'));
```

```css
  

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
#animated {
  width: 100px;
/* sets height to a height variable*/
  height: var(--height);
  border: 2px solid black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 30%;
/* sticks div to a bottom of parent conatainer*/
 bottom: 0;
 animation: grow 4s infinite;
transition: height 4s;
}


/*use calc to calculate start and end animation height*/
@keyframes grow {
  0% { height: calc(var(--height) - var(--height)); }
  50%{ height: var(--height); }
  100% { height: calc(var(--height) - var(--height)); }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="animated"></div>
</div>
```

You can set duration or whatever the same way.

Comment: Your answer goes part way to helping, though the height does not go right down, but it would be more useful if you could also add an explanation of what has changed and what makes it work.

Comment: Ye i guess i have changed the height to go up, but his question was how to fix it and then change height up and down. So i just done that. But i have edited my answer. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic example of how you could lay out an absolutely positioned animation so that the bottom remains fixed in place.

As mentioned in the comments, the important part is the `bottom: 0` (Or whatever fixed value works for your situation)

```css
/* A wrapper component, the only important part here is the position relative */
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.animated {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0; /* This fixes the bar to the bottom of the wrapper element */
  width: 20px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
  /* Some animation for demo purposes */
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: animate-height;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes animate-height {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
  
  to {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="animated"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, my new height is given as a parameter, so I need to use js to animate the new height, am i wrong?